# Code Optimization in ruby array

Tags: ruby, csv, optimization

How to optimize below code into single or couple steps. Is there any array method to do below stuff?

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a.each_slice(2).to_a.each do |nested_arr|
  nested_arr.each do |val|
    row << val
  end
  csv << row  #sample csv object showed here to explain. 
end
```

The basic idea behind this is, avoid insertion of bulk data into a single csv file

Comment: "avoid insertion of bulk data into a single csv file" So... you want to split the data into multiple csv files? What are you trying to ask here?

Answer (score 2):

Do as below :

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a.each_slice(2) do |nested_arr|
  csv.puts(nested_arr) # considering csv is a CSV object.
end
```

[`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) takes a block, so no need `to_a.each` part to do with `a.each_slice(2)`. Then use [`CSV#puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-puts) methods to insert the data into the csv object.

I don't know how have you created the `csv` objects. So here is my approach :

```
require 'csv'

path = "C:\\Users\\test.csv"
a=(1..8).to_a
CSV.open(path,"w") do |csv|
    a.each_slice(2) do |nested_arr|
      csv.puts(nested_arr)
    end
end
```